# Kali Linux after apt dist-upgrade error with Nouveau & installing NVIDIA drivers "No Space Left on Device"

Tags: kali-linux, login, nouveau

I have a Kali Linux machine. Last weekend I updated Kali with `apt update` /`apt dist-upgrade`, and when I rebooted the machine it wouldn't let me log in. At first everything was normal, grub loads the same what is necessary and the login form is displayed. When I enter my credentials it seems to enter but it sends a black screen for a moment and then immediately returns to the login form

1. The first error is the login error, I recorded with my cell phone to see if I could see what it said and I found the following:

[image: First error]

Investigating I see that the problem is in the nouveau drivers and that I must install the NVIDIA drivers. At least that's what I understood, according to all the forums and special settings of the nouveau driver like that don't work :

```
blacklist nouveau 
options nouveau modeset=0
drm modeset=0
nouveau modeset=0
```

2. Second error: Investigating how to install the NVIDIA driver in Kali, I log in in console mode (<kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>). I log in and try to install it first with the NVIDIA `.run` but I get many errors that I didn't understand at first until I tried `sudo apt update` where I notice a common message where it mentions that I no longer have storage space `No Space Left on Device` (although I remembered that I still had a minimum of 20GB).

I delete some dictionaries to free space but it is not freed even though I already cleaned the trash and I still have inodes available I have only used 7%, I try the `du` and `df -h` commands and if they confirm no space but i just delete something and it doesn't work.

Now I'm in a loop where I can't install the NVIDIA driver and I still don't seem to have space.

Any recommendations what I can do?

Comment: Using `apt dist-upgrade` is wrong, [here's how-to](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/updating-kali/). Have you added non-Kali repos to your `sources.list`? [According to Kali site](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/) "adding other operating system’s repositories into Kali (such as trying to put Ubuntu on Kali), **will** break your installation. This is the single most common reason why Kali Linux systems break.". Kali isn't a desktop distro, it's a toolbox for security professionals, many of whom actually run it as a Virtual Machine.

Comment: "Any recommendations what I can do?" - Reinstall, and don't use it as a daily driver.